# Node server, html input null

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, express-router

I'm am trying to serve a front end application with node, just learning the basics of express. The issue that i'm having is that my javascript which i've linked into my html **via an SRC cannot access the DOM**. if console.log(document) I can see the entire document object as a string, but if I try to access anything inside that like the form or the body it returns **NULL**. null null null null null. For example, console.log( document.getElementById('input') ) logs null to the browser, while console.log(document) logs the document to the browser. My css loaded in the same way works just fine. Why is this? How to get around it?

path: weather/src/weather.html

html:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <title>The Weather</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/weather.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='weather.css'/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='entry'>
    <h1>Weather</h1>
    <form name='add_address' action='#'>
      <input id="input" name='address' type='text' placeholder='Street Address, Zip, State' maxlength='60'>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

path: weather/router.js

Router.js:

```
 const path = require('path'),
  express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router(),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  app = express(),
  port = 3000

app.listen(port)

router.get( '/weather', (req, res)=>{
   res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname + '/src/weather.html' ))
})
router.get( '/weather.css', (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname + '/src/weather.css' ))
})

app.get('/weather.js', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname + '/src/weather.js'))
})
app.use('/', router)
```

Comment: _just learning the basics of express_ if you are learning then you must use `express.static` to serve static resources

Comment: and please check your network tab is request is being sent for those files and in response you get `200`

Comment: Moreover, load your script after the DOM loaded i-e move this line `<script type='text/javascript' src='/weather.js'></script>` at the end

Comment: Why is it you recommend using express static for beginners?

Comment: coz this is how things works. Why not learn/avail the provided functionalities provided by the framework when you've decided to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

@George Bailey. Thanks. Script was running before the DOM loaded. Need to brush up on some of the basics I guess.

```
<head>
  <title>The Weather</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='weather.css'/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='entry'>
    <h1>Weather</h1>
    <form name='add_address' action=''>
      <input id="input" name='address' type='text' placeholder='Street Address, Zip, State' maxlength='60'>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
<footer>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='./weather.js'></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: well, you should not post answer to your own question. You better let me know if that worked so I could post it as an answer and you could accept it -:)

Comment: If you write an answer I will delete this one and upvote that one. @GeorgeBailey